# Need to Print SQL Record Set values in to Excel

Tags: excel, vbscript, qtp, vba

Upon printing the (SQL)record set values, only the fields from first row gets printed. i need help to print all the fields from a record set using QTP VB script.

Comment: Please read the [ask] section, then reword your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
For i=0 to rs.Fields.Count-1 
DB_Data.cells(1,i+1).value = rs.fields(i).Name
rs.MoveNext 
Next
```

Here in above loop added rs.movenext to traverse all d records in data set.

DB_Data.Range(DB_Data.cells(1,1), _ DB_Data.cells(1,rs.Fields.Count)).Font.Bold = True

```
j = 0
k = 2
Do Until rs.EOF 
k=j+1 
DB_Data.cells(k+1,k).value = rs.fields(j).Name 
rs.MoveNext
j= j+1 
Loop
```

Here looping construct had some problem so did some changes accordingly. Hope this may work.